# Pandas table re-shape | creating datetime column with hours

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, reshape

I'm trying to reshape a table with pandas. Date column with 365 rows for each day of the year. 24 columns for each hour and 24 columns for each value corresponding for the hour of that day. I am trying to create a column with day + hour (24 rows for each day) and column with the corresponding value. Here is a current head():

```
Date          |    hour1     |    value1    |   hour2    |    value2    ... hour24    |     value 24

2016-01-01   |   1  |     4100  |    2   |    3500   |    24   |     5200

Here is the desired format:

Date                   |       value 

2016-01-01 01    |   4100

2016-01-01 02    |   3500

....

2016-01-01 24    |   5200
```

I've tried with melt and pivoting but cannot get sorted day + hour column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) by `dict`, then add `hour`s converted to [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and last remove column `A` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and if necessary [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `Date` column:

```
print (df)
         Date  hour1  value1  hour2  value2  hour24  value24
0  2016-01-01      1    4100      2    3500      24     5200
1  2016-01-02      1    3000      2    3700      24     7200

a = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('hour')]
b = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('value')]

df = pd.lreshape(df, {'A' : a, 'B' : b})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['A'], unit='h')
df = df.drop('A', axis=1).sort_values('Date')
print (df)
                 Date     B
0 2016-01-01 01:00:00  4100
2 2016-01-01 02:00:00  3500
4 2016-01-02 00:00:00  5200
1 2016-01-02 01:00:00  3000
3 2016-01-02 02:00:00  3700
5 2016-01-03 00:00:00  7200
```

Another solution is create [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) by [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
mux = df.columns.to_series().str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)', expand=True) 
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([mux[0], mux[1]], names=('a','b'))
df = df.stack(1).reset_index()
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'], unit='h')
df = df.drop(['b', 'hour'], axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
                 Date  value
0 2016-01-01 01:00:00   4100
1 2016-01-01 02:00:00   3500
2 2016-01-02 00:00:00   5200
3 2016-01-02 01:00:00   3000
4 2016-01-02 02:00:00   3700
5 2016-01-03 00:00:00   7200
```